# How to return 1 in mysql_insert_id() in php?

Tags: php, mysql

The logical error here is that the `mysql_insert_id()` always starts at 0 and I want it to increment from 1 and so on. I wonder why it gives me an error: Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'. I don't want to duplicate the key I just want to add it.
eg. 1 2 3 4.

Here's my code:

```
$insertID=mysql_insert_id(); //I want this to start at 1

        if (isset($_POST['lastname']) && isset($_POST['firstname']) && isset($_POST['address']))
        {
            $sql="INSERT INTO contact(idnum, lastname, firstname, address) values ('$insertID','$_POST[lastname]','$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[address]')";

            if(!mysql_query($sql, $con))
            {
                    die("Error: " .mysql_error());
            }
            echo "Saved...";
        }
```

Comment: cheat

because the table has no seed to start from

add a dummy record with that ID, everything after will count from there

that's what i did anyways, works like a charm

Comment: why do you want to get the ID before even inserting an record ?

Comment: I want the program to provide the id.

Comment: Just remove the column from the insert query. The database will insert the id on it self, since the column is set to auto increment.

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be misunderstanding [what `mysql_insert_id()` actually does](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php).

It doesn't generate an ID for you to use in your *next* query.  It tells you the ID that *MySQL generated* in the *last* query.  So...

1. If your table isn't using an auto-generated ID, there's no generated ID for the database to return.
2. You're asking for the generated ID before you insert anything.

If you're using a manual ID, then it's the responsibility of your application to generate a unique one.  If you're using a database-generated ID, then remove the ID from your INSERT statement and get the ID from the database *after* it's been generated.

---

Also, side note, your code is ***wide open to [SQL injection vulnerabilities](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)***.